# AttributeError: module 'pynput.keyboard' has no attribute 'key'

Tags: python

i was trying to make a hot key and my code isnt working i would like to get some answer why is it not working this is the code 
ok so for everyone with the same prob you just need to see what is with a capital character and what is not

```
from pynput import keyboard

COMBINATIONS=[
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='a')},
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='A')}
    ]

current = set()

def execute():
    print ("detected hotkey")

def on_press(Key):
    if any([Key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute()

def on_release(Key):
    if any([Key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
            current.remove(Key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as Listener:
            Listener.join()
```

and every time i run it it prints out this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\raz parnes\Documents\coding\hot key.py", line 4, in <module>
    {keyboard.key.shift, keyboard.keycode(char='a')},
AttributeError: module 'pynput.keyboard' has no attribute 'key'
```

Comment: Isn't it Key and not key: `keyboard.Key` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is case-sensitive and it looks like there is a `keyboard.Key` with capital K. `keyboard.Listener` and `keyboard.KeyCode` also start from upper case:

```
COMBINATIONS=[
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='a')},
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='A')}
    ]

...

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
            listener.join()
```

Comment: i did and it prints a huge text when im running the program and pressing the hot key the text is so big i cant fit it in one comment

Comment: The argument name is `Key` with capital K :P

Comment: tysm tho it still not working after im running it im pressing the hot key and it prints the hot key found message and then it prints this text i put the text in the main post if you could help me that would be amazing                 tysm yoni

Comment: and if you could help me put a try and except becuse i dont remember how to use it                  tysm-yoni

Comment: i figured out what is the problem you need to press the hot key(shift+a) in the same time and it is just not possible is there a chance to make it not just at the same time?

Comment: im sorry if im disturbing you im 12y/o and im studing python with my dad and english is not my mine languge so im pretty bad at it

Comment: @yoni above you indicated that you 'need to press the hot key(shift+a) in the same time', That is not normally the situation. Normally you have to hold down the modifier key(s) like the shift key and then the main key (the a).